# Is there a way to easily find methods/functions available in a Flutter package?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

For example, I imported the english_words package to the pubspec.yaml and main.dart files. Is there any way to easily see the list of available functions/methods/features on Android Studio that I can use (without having to manually go to the file's path and opening the docs in the notepad)?

[image]